# Sort three numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, julia

So, I wrote this function to sort three numbers in Julia. Any feedback on readability, performance, and Julian-ness would be appreciated.

```julia
function sort_asc(a, b, c)
    # defined in function so as not to overwrite Base.minmax
    minmax(x, y) = ifelse(x < y, (x, y), (y, x))

    l1, h1 = minmax(a, b)
    lo, h2 = minmax(l1, c)
    md, hi = minmax(h1, h2)

    return lo, md, hi
end
```

Comment: There's no need to swap `x` and `y` if they're equal, so I'd prefer less-or-equal instead of less-than.

Comment: Have a look at the code in [SortingNetworks.jl](https://github.com/JeffreySarnoff/SortingNetworks.jl). They seem to be using your approach, but with a branching `minmax`. Probably for good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out

```julia
function sort_asc(a, b, c)
    l1, h1 = minmax(a, b)
    lo, h2 = minmax(l1, c)
    md, hi = minmax(h1, h2)
    return lo, md, hi
end
```

results in the exact same native assembly instructions on my machine (compared to the branchless version). So, given its greater simplicity, I think this is the best version so far.

Here are comparisons to other implementations

```julia
function sort3(a, b, c)
    l1, h1 = minmax(a, b)
    lo, h2 = minmax(l1, c)
    md, hi = minmax(h1, h2)
    return lo, md, hi
end

@inline minmax_nb(x, y) = ifelse(isless(x, y), (x, y), (y, x))

function sort3_nb(a, b, c)
    l1, h1 = minmax_nb(a, b)
    lo, h2 = minmax_nb(l1, c)
    md, hi = minmax_nb(h1, h2)
    return lo, md, hi
end

function sort3_koen(a, b, c)
    lo, md = minmax(a, b)
    if md > c
        hi = md
        lo, md = minmax(lo, c)
    else
        hi = c
    end

    return lo, md, hi
end
```

Here is the benchmark code

```julia
using BenchmarkTools

function map_sort3!(f::F, out, data) where F
    @inbounds for i in eachindex(out, data)
        a, b, c = data[i]
        out[i]  = f(a, b, c)
    end
end

for f in [sort3, sort3_nb, sort3_koen]
    print(rpad(f, 12), ":")
    @btime map_sort3!($f, out, data) setup=begin
        data = [ntuple(i -> rand(Int), 3) for _ in 1:10_000]
        out = similar(data)
    end evals=1
end
```

And here are the results on my machine:

```
sort3       :  17.286 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
sort3_nb    :  17.624 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
sort3_koen  :  21.776 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect this to be marginally faster:

```
(lo,md) = minmax(a,b)
if md > c
       hi = md
       (lo,md) = minmax(lo,c)
else
       hi = c
```

I don't know where this sits in the scale of Julianesquinness since I'm not familiar with Julia (not even sure if my "if-else" adheres to its syntax, but the intention should be clear).